# How to make a wall of pictures clickable that sends away a value

Tags: html, css, jsp

in HTML I have this wall of pictures with different foods.

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Sallad</p><img src="img/sallad.jpg"></li>
    <li><p>Pizza</p><img src="img/pizza.jpg"></li>
    <li><p>Sushi</p><img src="img/Sushi.jpg"></li>
    <li><p>Pasta</p><img src="img/pasta.jpeg"></li>
    <li><p>Indian</p><img src="img/indian.jpeg"></li>
    <li><p>Fish</p><img src="img/fish.jpeg"></li>
    <li><p>Burger</p><img src="img/burger.jpeg"></li>
    <li><p>Steak</p><img src="img/steak.jpeg"></li>
    <li><p>Vegetarian</p><img src="img/vegetarian.jpeg"></li>

 </ul>
```

My problem is basically that I have a search function, when I click on one of these pictures I want it to redirect me to another page, I know I can basically use `<a href` for this, but the thing is I want each of these picture to have one value so that my search function can read it and then display the search result from the database. I.E If I click the pasta picture, it will take me to the result page showing all the pasta dishes in the database.

If any of you have any other suggestions or solutions I would really appraciate it. Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Fyi, it's "salad" and not "sallad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="The URL of the site"><img src="The URL of the image"></a>
```

**Example**

```
<li><p>Sallad</p><a href="sallad.html"><img src="img/sallad.jpg"></a></li>
```

OR

```
<li><p>Sallad</p><a href="search.jsp?search=sallad"><img src="img/sallad.jpg"></a></li>
```

**UPDATE**

Try This

```
    <li><a href="sallad.html"><p>Sallad</p></a><img src="img/sallad.jpg"></li>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, yeah the thing is I built this picture wall using this guide http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-an-animated-photo-wall-with-css/, but somehow when I add a href to it, it wont let me click on it.

Comment: @Carloos You will get good answer. If you will explain your exact problem

Comment: if you check the link I posted, there is an example there. I did the a href like you guys suggested, but when I click on the img's nothing happens. That's why I posted the link to see if you can understand why it isn't working, maybe something about the CSS or HTML structure that prevents the a href tag to respond when I click.

Comment: @Carloos ok, i will go through and will back with your solution.

Comment: @Carloos have you checked their demo here http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/PhotoWall/fade.html. Have you done till here ??

Comment: @Carloos please review my update and let me know, if you have any problem.

Comment: thanks so much sir! I'm sorry I had to go out for a while, just got home to my parents since its christmas and all! I'll check as soon as the guests leaves, thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: About what you wrote earlier, I did exact the same as the  designshack.net/tutorialexamples/PhotoWall/fade.html. I did what you said about javascript, but nothing happens still when I click on the picture. when you wrote onclick="move(this)" thats what I was suppose to write right?

Comment: did it work for you when you tried it on that model? could it be the CSS that is the problem? Because when I hold the mouse over it it zooms in and adds a black layer with the name of the food, could that be the reason that the img isn't responsive to the click?

Comment: I've checked, it seems like there must be something with the CSS, I did what you said in the regular way just the codes outside of the ul and it worked, do you know how to bypass the CSS in a way?

Comment: Thank you sir, its working! Merry Christmas to you and I'm really greatful!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a link that contains a query string.

```
<a href="whatever.jsp?search=salad"><img src="..."></a>
```

Do it likewise for the other elements. In your server-side code you can then access the GET variable named "search".

Comment: oh wow, how did I not think about that before! Thank you Master! :) I'm really new to HTML.

Comment: good sir I used this to build the wall, http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-an-animated-photo-wall-with-css/, could you possibly check this out real quick? because I used the  a href but it wont let me click at all for some reason.